# React native Flatlist official documentation not rendering

Tags: react-native

I took the example in official React native documentation to apply, just changed few things that should not matter at all, and added `<Text>` so I can make sure the component is exported properly in my parent component.

The part with `List problem` shows but the list itself doesn't show. I tested `Scollview` with mapping `DATA` before `Flatlist` and it worked but Flatlist doesn't work.

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text,  SafeAreaView, FlatList, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

function Item({ title }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const ListOfTrips = () => {
  const DATA = [
    {
      id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
      title: 'First Item',
    },
    {
      id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
      title: 'Second Item',
    },
    {
      id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
      title: 'Third Item',
    },
  ];

  return (
    <View>
      <Text> List problem </Text>
     <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item.title} />}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 250,
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 32,
  },
});

export default ListOfTrips;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is because of **SafeAreaView** placing is not proper. Refactor your return as

```
 return (
      <SafeAreaView>
          <Text> List problem </Text>
          <FlatList
              data={DATA}
              renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item.title} />}
              keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          />
      </SafeAreaView>
  );
```

The **SafeAreaView** should be used as root tag of the screen to avoid view mis alignment in notch devices.
Kindly refer [React-Native SafeAreaView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/safeareaview)

Comment: I didn't need SafeAreaView in this place as it is already rendered inside a component, so I removed it and it worked. Thank you :)